# Why is the TimeSeries chart not generating in Android when using a chart engine?

Tags: android

I am trying to generate time series chart using a chart engine in Android, but it's not generated.

This is my code:

```
TimeSeries oxygen = new TimeSeries("D.O");
TimeSeries phvalue = new TimeSeries("Ph");
TimeSeries tempvalue = new TimeSeries("Temparature");

for(int i=0;i<timeshowchart.size();++i){
    try{
    oxygen.add(timeshowchart.get(i), OxygenArray.get(i));
    phvalue.add(timeshowchart.get(i), PhArray.get(i));
    tempvalue.add(timeshowchart.get(i), TempArray.get(i));
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am getting errors like this:

```
08-05 19:01:13.416: E/AndroidRuntime(15557): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
08-05 19:01:13.416: E/AndroidRuntime(15557): Process: com.techeruvaka.pondguard, PID: 15557
08-05 19:01:13.416: E/AndroidRuntime(15557): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 7, size is 7 
08-05 19:01:13.416: E/AndroidRuntime(15557): at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255) 
    E/AndroidRuntime(15557): java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308):
    E/AndroidRuntime(15557): at org.achartengine.util.IndexXYMap.getYByIndex(IndexXYMap.java:86)
```

Comment: 08-05 19:01:13.416: E/AndroidRuntime(15557): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-05 19:01:13.416: E/AndroidRuntime(15557): Process: com.techeruvaka.pondguard, PID: 15557
08-05 19:01:13.416: E/AndroidRuntime(15557): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 7, size is 7
08-05 19:01:13.416: E/AndroidRuntime(15557):  at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
 E/AndroidRuntime(15557): java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308): E/AndroidRuntime(15557):  at org.achartengine.util.IndexXYMap.getYByIndex(IndexXYMap.java:86)


i am getting errors like this

Comment: i did not get your suggestion.